# Return a new object for each Returns() in NSubstitute

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nsubstitute

I have created a substitute which mocks a web service interface for my  unit testing which includes the following method definition:

```
public Message Invoke(Message input)
```

This method is called using:

```
var reply = webService.Invoke(messageObject)
```

When I make multiple calls to the same method, it is throwing the following exception:

System.InvalidOperationException : This message cannot support the operation because it has been read.

Here is my Nsubstitute mock code:

```
outputMessageObj = GetResponseMessage()
wsMock.Invoke(Arg.Any<Message>()).Returns(outputMessageObj)
```

How do I ensure that a new outputMessage object is returned each time the call is made?

Answer (score 11):

Got it, just use a lambda to invoke a method which returns a new Message object each time:

```
wsMock.Invoke(Arg.Any<Message>()).Returns(x => GetResponseMessage())
```

Comment: If you want return particular values in the order, you can pass all values you want to return to the `Returns` method. `wsMock.Invoke(null).ReturnsForAnyArgs(response1, response2, response3);`